# Cufon Superfish hide dropdown text in IE8 

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, drop-down-menu, cufon, superfish

I am using Cofunized text in my drop downs with superfish. But dropdown text is hidden in IE8. I try this fix but no luck instead it stopped working in every browser. The fix is: https://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-fix-superfish-cufon-in-ie8.

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
    Cufon.CSS.ready(function(){ 

        $("ul#nav_709109").supersubs({ 
            minWidth:    12,   // minimum width of sub-menus in em units 
            maxWidth:    27,   // maximum width of sub-menus in em units 
            extraWidth:  1     // extra width can ensure lines don't sometimes turn over 
                               // due to slight rounding differences and font-family 
        }).superfish({ 
            autoArrows:  true, // disable generation of arrow mark-up 
            dropShadows: false // disable drop shadows 
        }); 
    });     
   Cufon.replace('#main-nav li a', {fontFamily:'GRMedium',hover: true});

   </script>
```

Comment: Please, do the web a favour and stop using cufon. Use `@font-face` which is superior and globally supported.

Comment: Font-face is not globally supported, at least not with otf and ttf (until IE9) . The majority of fonts are not provided in eof format, and you would have to change it to that using a generator.. If you do want something working and performing in all major browsers, try to find a nice font in the Google Web fonts API and collection.

Comment: I can not use Font-face as I don't have choice. Can any one please help me to sort this out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

specify a height for your element might fix your problem. If not, could you provide us your code or an url or something so we can take a closer look?

Comment: sorry Imran, cant help you much with only this. Could you also provide the css and html so i can take a closer look? maybe use jsfiddle.net for it?